# DRY - Loops that creates tables

Tags: javascript, arrays

Im storing data in arrays, from that arrays im creating table with loops. For one table I need two columns, for another 30 (depends on array items). This going to have three columns.

```
var prodej = [
  /*First column, second, third column*/
  ["Jack", 100, 101],
  ["Bkack", 100, 5],
  ["Duck", 100, 9],
];
```

And here is my loop

```
for ( var i = 0; prodej.length > i; i += 1) {
  var tr = '<tr>'
  var td1 = '<td>' + prodej[i][0]; + '</td>'
  var td2 = '<td>' + prodej[i][1]; + '</td>'
  var td3 = '<td>' + prodej[i][2]; + '</td>'
  tr += td1 + td2 + td3 + '</tr>'
  $("#firstTable").append(tr);
}
```

And here is another array and loop for it

```
var another = [

  ["Buick", 100],
  ["Ford", 100],
  ["Nissan", 100],
];

for ( var i = 0; another.length > i; i += 1) {
  var tr = '<tr>'
  var td1 = '<td>' + another[i][0]; + '</td>'
  var td2 = '<td>' + another[i][1]; + '</td>'
  tr += td1 + td2 +  '</tr>'
  $("#secondTable").append(tr);
}
```

I see a lot of same code, but I don't know what can I do for to have just one loop. Goals is

- get lenght of inner array and based on that create same number td in tr
- create unique id bassed on array name

Comment: What do these tables look like? We'd need to know their relationship to answer this successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a function that takes the array and the id as arguments. Use nested loops to create the cells.

```
function createTable(data, id) {
  for (var i = 0; data.length > i; i += 1) {
    var tr = '<tr>';
    for (var j = 0; data[i].length > j; j += 1) {
      tr += '<td>' + data[i][j]; + '</td>';
    }
    tr += '</tr>';
    $("#" + id).append(tr);
  }
}
```

Then you can call this function when you want to create your table:

```
 createTable(prodej, 'firstTable');
 createTable(another, 'secondTable');
```

Comment: @Ostrov Because of this `var html += '<td>'`

Comment: Thanks, it is fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, seems simple and great. I removed } at first line ;) and added few words to allow me save it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [table api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTableElement):

```js
function populateTable(table, rowsData) {
  rowsData.forEach(function(rowData) {
    var row = table.insertRow();

    rowData.forEach(function(cellData) {
      var cell = row.insertCell();

      var text = document.createTextNode(cellData);

      cell.appendChild(text);
    });
  });
}

var prodej = [
  ["Jack", 100, 101],
  ["Bkack", 100, 5],
  ["Duck", 100, 9]
];

var table1 = document.getElementById('table1');

populateTable(table1, prodej);

var another = [
  ["Buick", 100],
  ["Ford", 100],
  ["Nissan", 100]
];
var table2 = document.getElementById('table2');

populateTable(table2, another);
```

```html
<table id="table1"></table>

<br />

<br />

<table id="table2"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a function that will test to see how long the array is, then how long the current element of the array is. You can then reuse the function passing it an array and a table to append too.

```js
var prodej = [
    /*First column, second, third column*/
    ["Jack", 100, 101],
    ["Bkack", 100, 5],
    ["Duck", 100, 9],
];

var another = [
    ["Buick", 100],
    ["Ford", 100],
    ["Nissan", 100],
];
var myTable = $('#firstTable');

DRYLoop(another, myTable);

function DRYLoop(array, table) {

    for (var i = 0; array.length > i; i += 1) {
        table.append('<tr>');

        for (var d = 0; d < array[i].length; d++) {
            table.append('<td>' + array[i][d] + '</td>');
        }
        table.append('</tr>');
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="firstTable">

</table>
```